# ng-repeat not working on Array of objects on directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular1.6

I have a `directive` which looks as follows. The variable `testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber]` is defined in the parent controller and has data in it. It is an array of `Objects`. It is printed by `{{$parent.testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber]}}` in the below code. 
By when I do `ng-repeat` , it does not work and does not throw an error as well. What am I missing?

```
<div id="test-data" class="test-data-table">
        <h3 style="text-align:center;" ng-if="!testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber]">No test Data</h3>

        {{$parent.testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber]}}
        <table ng-if="$parent.testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber]" class="left">
            <tr>
                <th>test</th>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>Capacity</th>
                <th>Updated</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in $parent.testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber]  track by $index">
                <td>{{data.test}}

                </td>
                <td>{{data.itemDescription}}</td>
                <td>{{data.amount}}/{{data.testCapacity}}</td>
                <td>{{data.lastUpdatedDate | date :"h:mm" }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The `testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber]` looks lik as follows

```
[{"plant_":" 0205","plantName":"Mrs. Edgardo Lockman LTD ","test":"1A ","item_":"30100060 ","itemDescription":"AC BASE 301 ","amount":0,"testCapacity":200,"plantCapacityPerHour":350,"plantCapacityPerShift":3000,"lastUpdatedDate":"2017-01-19T16:45:00","lasttestTransaction":251355},{"plant_":" 0205","plantName":"Mrs. Edgardo Lockman LTD ","test":"1B ","item_":"14800060 ","itemDescription":"AC SURFACE 448 TY 1 ","amount":0,"testCapacity":200,"plantCapacityPerHour":350,"plantCapacityPerShift":3000,"lastUpdatedDate":"2017-01-19T16:45:00","lasttestTransaction":251355},{"plant_":" 0205","plantName":"Mrs. Edgardo Lockman LTD ","test":"1C ","item_":"14800060 ","itemDescription":"AC SURFACE 448 TY 1 ","amount":0,"testCapacity":220,"plantCapacityPerHour":350,"plantCapacityPerShift":3000,"lastUpdatedDate":"2017-01-19T16:45:00","lasttestTransaction":251355}]
```

Comment: can you add code where you define testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber] ?

Comment: @Jenny That is inside  the controller which is displaying this directive.

Comment: Do you checked that testDataWithPlantNumberAsKey[plantnumber] is array?

Comment: Yes that's an array. I have checked

Comment: I have added the array above & it's displayed inside the directive if print it .. I just cannot ng-repeat that

Comment: I think you need to deserialize this Json array to object array before using in ng-repeat

Comment: @Jenny the issue was usage of `ng-if` Anyway thanks for helping it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the issue, it was using `ng-if` which creates a different scope, whereas $parent refers to the immediate previous scope!